# Can Ramda improve this?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I am discovering Ramda library and trying to wrap my mind around functional programming. I would like to know if there is a cleaner way to implement a function like this using Ramda:

```
const replace = (template, dict) =>
  Object.keys(dict).reduce(
    (template, key) => template.replace(key, dict[key]),
    template
  );
```

I can only think of this way, which feels pretty much the same thing:

```
const replace = (template, dict) =>
  R.reduce(
    (template, key) => R.replace(key, dict[key], template),
    template,
    Object.keys(dict)
  );
```

I would find no sense using Ramda here. Is there any advantage I am not seeing? Is there any other cleaner way to implement this with Ramda?

Comment: you should checkout code-review or programming stackexcahnges.

Comment: I would change `Object.keys(dict).reduce((template, key) => {...` to `R.toPairs(dict).reduce((template, [key, value]) => {...`. If you're using babel or targetting only the most recent JS environments then `Object.entries` has the same effect.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking for improvements to working code belong on Code Review, not Stack Overflow.